# Error when converting date to specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following format for my dates
1952-02-04 00:00:00

I need the format to be `month/day/year`

How do I go about this currently I have

```
if clientDob is not None:
            clientDob = datetime.datetime.strptime(clientDob, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

the error I get is

> time data 'Birth Dt' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: your format must match ` 1952-02-04 00:00:00` -add the hours:minutes:seconds format specifier.

Comment: This is my first time working with datetime. is it just adding 3 more %d fields? Thanks Patrick.

Comment: Check what the value of `clientDob` is. Looks like it's `"Birth Dt"` rather than the actual date.

Comment: Yes it is a birth date. How do I fix my format specifier to include this time argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
clientDob = datetime.datetime.strptime(clientDob, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

for datetime parsing your string must match the source string *exactly*. It contains time-information, you need to match it.

```
import datetime 
clientDob = "2018-12-21 12:13:14"

clientDob = datetime.datetime.strptime(clientDob, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
print(clientDob)
```

Output:

```
12/21/18
```

Details: [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)